# Iterate and change values of Class constants in py3

Tags: python, python-3.x, class

I am trying to iterate over a `class.__dict__` and change its constants. My working code works for python 2, but not for python three. Here is the code that works in py2:

```
class SOMECLASS:
    a = 'Something'
    b = 'Something else'

change = vars(SOMECLASS)
for k, v in change.items():
    if not '__' in k:
        change[k] = 'some_new_value'
```

Using this code standalone is py3 throws `TypeError: 'mappingproxy' object does not support item assignment`. To bypass this, I made this change to the code:

```
change = dict(vars(rng.JSCSS))
```

But this does not work because when the loop stops, `change` is back to its original value. Googling, the `setattr` function keeps coming up, but that does not apply to what i am looking to accomplish.

I am actually converting my original code which was meant for py2 to work for py3 also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`setattr`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#setattr) does apply here, and you can use it to change a class's attributes:

```
class SOMECLASS:
    a = 4
    b = 4

change = vars(SOMECLASS)


for i in change:
    if not '__' in i:
        setattr(SOMECLASS, i, 5)

x = SOMECLASS()
print(x.a)
```

Output:

```
5
```